# How to pass first component id to second component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

My question is that i have two model one is product and taxproduct. here i have mention one to many relationship i have mapped product id into taxproduct.  in this component.ts Save_user is an product  service. And Save_tax is an taxproduct. first i want to insert product and i want to take that id to map with TAxproduct.

**component.ts**

```
 createNewProduct(productForm: NgForm) {
    this.productService.save_user(productForm.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('success', 'New Product', 'Inserted Successfully');
        this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
        this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
      },
        error => {
          const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('error', 'New Product', 'Error Occurred!!');
          this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
          this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
        });
 for (let i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.contacts[i])
          this.productService.save_tax(JSON.stringify(this.contacts[i] )).subscribe(response => {
            const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('success', 'New Product', 'Inserted Successfully');
            this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
            this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
          },
            error => {
              const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('error', 'New Product', 'Error Occurred!!');
              this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
              this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
            });
        }
  }
```

**Model.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='myphoto/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, max_length=255)
    pro_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    taxable = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    tax_details= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    type_units = models.ForeignKey(Units, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hsn = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Taxproduct(models.Model):
    tax_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tax_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call second service inside first service's subscribe method, if I understand some part of your problem. If you want your component to be created from something that's returned from an http response, you'll to wait before your component can be created for http response to return.

Comment: Actually im new to angular2. so i have confused. i not able to map main form id. it throws error like {"product_id":["This field is required."]} . could you please tell me how to do that

Comment: Your query is still unclear. Please paste more code and explain your problem in parts.

Comment: I have mentioned my model and component.ts so please check the code above.

Comment: "first i want to insert product and i want to take that id to map with TAxproduct" -> I suppose you're doing first part correctly. I don't understand what you're trying to do next. What is "that id"?
In your function, you're basically saving the parameter passed to the function, via a service. That is understandable. Next you're iterating through contacts array and saving each object in that array. Can you throw some code to show where does contacts come in picture? Maybe some HTML will help.